# android studio gradle synch error after updating to 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I had an android project running well, but suddenly I encountered some errors which made me update my android studio to 3.2.1 and gradle to 4.6. My code is same as my colleague (all codes and versions) except one line in gradle that I will explain it later, he can build easily but I can't because of following errors:

```
Failed to resolve: espresso-core
Open File


Failed to resolve: multidex-instrumentation
Open File
```

app.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.arnick.bazim"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.7"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

                                    onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        }
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1' 
// the above line is showing error to me, error is about some version mismatching
// even by doing what it says the error does not disappear
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
        implementation 'com.stephentuso:welcome:1.4.1'
        implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
            // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        }
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have cleaned, rebuiled, invalidated cache an restart and everything I have seen online. I even change maven reposiroty url to 2 or 3 other but error persists. What should I do? tnx

Comment: maybe related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30